# Vuej.s: How pass variable to component attribute

Tags: vue.js, components

How can i pass variable to component in Vue.js (not via `props`)? Is that possible?

Here app.js:

```
import PlayingField from '../app/components/PlayingField'
import GameConfig from '../../gameConfig'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        playingfield: PlayingField,
    },
    data: {
        gameConfig: GameConfig
    }
});
```

In game config is json and there is key 'maxUniqueCards' and this value i want in component playingField... No in template but in attribute to next work with it... (generate cards, order.... just for usage in playingField component methods...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$parent` property:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    App
    <input type="text" v-model="propTest">
    <Child />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from '@/components/Child.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { Child },
  data: () => ({
    propTest: 'abc',
  }),
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    child
    <button @click="test">Test</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Child',
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log(this.$parent.propTest);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Be careful with this property, you must use in edge cases: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Parent-Component-Instance